# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent $\iff \lim_{k\to \infty}[\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n]=0$. Is this right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ is convergent $\iff $ $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\bigg[\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n\bigg ]=0$

I don't know whether this statement is true or not. I think I'm sure that the from left to right statement is right, and here is my thought:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ is convergent, and suppose $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=A$. Then $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\bigg[\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n\bigg ]=A-\lim_{p\to \infty}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^p a_n=A-A=0$. Thus from left to right is right.

However, I'm not sure about the other side. My intuition tells me the other side might be right. By the same expression, $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\bigg[\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n\bigg ]=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\lim_{p\to \infty}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^p a_n$. If the $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ isn't convergent. Then the result should not exist instead of being zero, but I'm not sure.

Any help on this? Thanks!

Comment: What kinds of objects are the $a_n$ and infinite series thereof? For example, if we're restricted to the metric space $\Bbb Q$, then some Cauchy series seem not to converge, and that's because they really converge to an irrational number, which motivates Cauchy completion as a rival to Dedekind cuts to define $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Just $a_n \in \mathbb R$, and each $a_n$ is either positive, negative, or zero

Comment: @311411 Why this is true?

Comment: In epsilon-n, it said that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N\in \mathbb N: n>N...$. This $N$ is a fixed value, so if after $N$, and for $p=1,2,...$ $|a_n+...+a_{n+p}|<\epsilon$, this can mean that there are infinitely many terms, and their sum is smaller than epsilon, and the finitely many terms before them won't affect the convergence and divergence. This time we can say a series is convergent. But now $k$ isn't a fixed value, it is approaching infinity. Shouldn't this mean that there will be infinitely many terms before $k$ as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: The statement is true whenever it is a well-defined sentence (i.e., the sum $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n$ exists for all $k$.) It is risky to make a statement about some expressions that may be undefined in some instances.

Comment: A similar statement which is true, and doesn't involve possibly undefined terms is: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent if and only if $\lim_{k,\ell\to\infty} \sum_{n=k}^\ell a_n = 0$ (where the right hand side means: for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $k,\ell \ge N$, then $\left| \sum_{n=k}^\ell a_n \right| < \varepsilon$).

Comment: @Daniel Schepler I think I kind of understand your statement. By your statement, I can just let $l=k+p$ for $p\in \mathbb N$. Then when $l,k\to \infty$, the right side statement will just be the Cauchy criterion which implies that the series is convergent, right?

Comment: @311411 Do you mean that as $k\to infty$ I can fix $k$ for each time. When $k=1,2,3,...$. Then since the terms after $k$ gives 0 and the terms before it just $a_1+a_2+...,+a_{k-1}$, so the series is convergent?

Comment: @Yink I don't see what letting $\ell = k + p$ has to do with anything.  Otherwise, that's precisely the point: the condition implies the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy almost directly (with just the small wrinkle that $S_{\ell} - S_k = \sum_{n=k+1}^\ell a_n$ if $\ell > k$ or $-\sum_{n=\ell+1}^k a_n$ if $\ell < k$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your formula is that, in the right-hand side, we are confronted with an expression $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n$ that is undefined in some instances.

**1.** To make an analogy, consider the following formula:

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ x > 0 \iff 1/x > 0 \tag{1} $$

For the formula $\text{(1)}$ to have a truth value in formal logic, the function symbol $1/x$ must always have a value, even when $x = 0$. Of course, this is not the case under the usual definition of the division. So, how is this formula dealt with in logic? One solution is to say that $\text{(1)}$ is true iff it is true in any possible interpretation of the symbol $1/x$ (i.e., any assignment of value to the expression $1/0$). However, it is easy to see that the truth value of $\text{(1)}$ depends on the interpretation of $1/0$.

To make amend of this situation, we might tweak $\text{(1)}$ and instead consider

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ x > 0 \iff (x \neq 0 \text{ and } 1/x > 0). \tag{1'} $$

This statement is now true in arbitrary interpretation of the symbol $1/0$, hence we can serenely consider it true.

**2.** In the same spirit, we may modify your formula as:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \text{ converges in } \mathbb{R} \quad \iff \quad \left\{\begin{gathered} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n \text{ exists in } \overline{\mathbb{R}} \text{ for all } k \text{ and} \\\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n = 0\end{gathered}\right\} $$

where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]$. Then it is easy to check that this statement is true, as extensively discussed by other users.

Comment: To a downvoter: Please let me know why do you not like about this answer, so I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the theorem is true for real series. As already noted, a series converges iff its partial sums sequence converges (to a finite limit, to be crystal clear). Thus, we put

$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\;,\;\;\text{so that}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\;\;\text{converges}\;\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=S\in\Bbb R$$

and by the very definition of limit we get:

$$\left\{S_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\;\;\text{converges to a number}\;\,S\,\;\iff \forall\,\epsilon>0\;\;\exists\,N\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;n>N\implies |S-S_n|<\epsilon$$

But the last inequality is just

$$\epsilon>|S-S_n|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\right|$$

Thus we get that

$$\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\;\;\text{converges}\;\; \iff \;\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k=0$$

In fact, the above is just the definition of (finite) existence of limit after using
Cauchy's condition for the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Wrong answer. See the answer below.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What *exactly* in the above answer is wrong, in your opinion? Just to state "wrong" doesn't seem serious.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ on thn right side? You cannot use this meaningless sum  unless you know convergence already.  You should delete your answer.

Comment: That is the series tail or however you want to call it, and it converges to zero . Haven't you seen this? then you should study it. And it is **always** possible to talk about this even if a series diverges. Its behavior could be different, of course...but it is always defined as far as the series.

Comment: What does $\sum a_n$ denote if the partial sum sequence is $\{1,-1,1,-1,...\}$? It neither denotes  a real number nor $\pm \infty$. It has no value associated with it.  You have over 200K reputation points and youngsters assume that you know basic Mathematics.

Comment: I didn't talk about "sums" just like that. From the beginning it is *a converging series* that is being discussed. Partial sums are *always* defined . You have almost 300K reputation points, one could assume you actually understand what you're trying to write about...A pity.

Answer (score -2):

Note that convergence of series is usually defined as follows
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \text{ is convergent } :\Leftrightarrow \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)_{n} \text{ is converging}$$

Note that convergence of the term on the right hand side means: Let $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ it holds $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_k\right|\leq \varepsilon$. Then you have
$$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k -\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_k\right|\leq \varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary it follows $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is converging.

Comment: I think you regard the series as a sequence of partial sum and use the Cauchy criterion, but in fact, in my problem, the $\textbf{lower}$ index is approaching infinity instead of the upper one, so I think maybe this won't be helpful or did I miss something in your answer?

Comment: Yeah assume $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k=0$. This means that for any $\varepsilon$ you can choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k|<\varepsilon$. But in order to show that the series is converging you have to show that the partial sums are converging. But substracting the series from the $n$-th partial sum gives exactly $|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k|$ so that the series is converging.

Comment: Note that in my writings I changed $n$ and $k$ so thats maybe why you misunderstood me.